# Notation $Diff_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: notation

I have seen that, the set of all diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is denoted by $\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

> What about $\mathrm{Diff}_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Is it the set of all diffeomorphisms $ f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f$ is homotopic to $Id\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: It could mean many things, e.g., that $f(0)=0$, that $f$ is the identity outside of some compact set, etcetera. Somewhere in your source you'll find the intended meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually $\mathrm{Diff}_0(X)$ denotes the connected component of the identity in $\mathrm{Diff}(X)$, namely the set of diffeomorphisms of $X$ that are isotopic to the identity.

See for instance 
B. Farb, D. Margalit: *A primer in mapping class groups*, page 1.